# Is it possible to disable new bluetooth connections for non-admin accounts(Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, user-management, user-accounts, user-permissions, bluetooth

I can disable bluetooth entirely, but I want the previously attached bluetooth keyboard & mouse to continue working, but the guest/non-admin users unable to pair new devices. I looked at stopping Bluetooth Support Service, but that looks like it will also stop currently paired devices from working.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Bluetooth discoverability : Block option once you have configured with the desired device. When it configured it prevents